# Connection between a Java application and a database on Cloudera

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

as the title, I have a problem with the connection between a Java application and the database created on a virtual machine Cloudera.

A sample project application, which I placed, contains files with the extension .jar needed to connect.

Virtual machine network card is set to Host-Only.
Ip this virtual machine: 192.168.56.1.

I have no idea what to do next in order to be able to perform queries to the database.

Please help and sorry for my English.

Java Code:

```
package p;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class p{
    static Connection connection = null;
    static Statement statement = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://192.168.56.1:10000/przychodnia", "cloudera", "cloudera");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Wybierz");
        System.out.println("0 aby dodać do istniejącej tabeli wiersz");
        System.out.println("1 aby usunąć z istniejącej tabeli wiersz");
                String SQL = "SELECT * FROM pacjenci";
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);

                while (rs.next()){
                    String imie = rs.getString("imie");
                    String p = imie;
                    System.out.println(p);
    }
    }
}
```

Warnings:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500310) Invalid operation: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect;
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(HiveServer2ClientFactory.java:224)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.api.ExtendedHS2Factory.createClient(ExtendedHS2Factory.java:38)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCConnection.connect(HiveJDBCConnection.java:597)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(BaseConnectionFactory.java:219)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:216)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.cloudera.hive.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500310) Invalid operation: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect;
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:248)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(HiveServer2ClientFactory.java:210)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.api.ExtendedHS2Factory.createClient(ExtendedHS2Factory.java:38)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCConnection.connect(HiveJDBCConnection.java:597)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(BaseConnectionFactory.java:219)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:216)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at p.p.main(p.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
    ... 10 more
```

[image: JARS]

[image]

Comment: `Connection refused` means you have a networking problem, not directly a Java problem. Try `ping` and `telnet` and make sure the credentials are correct

Comment: Ping works fine, but telnet not. I have another question: i must use worker node ip address to connect right? I'm pasting new screenshots.

Comment: You would use the HiveServer2's IP address, if that is what you mean

Comment: `Column name not found` looks like it worked....

Comment: It works, thanks :D

Comment: It was a problem in my Java code :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ip this virtual machine: 192.168.56.1.

Your image that says "Column name not found" is using IP

```
192.168.56.101
```